# Unable to merge dex on Run Android App

Tags: android, gradle

i try run my application but suddenly arise this error

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

then i try searching and try that solution but all solution is not worked
help me :(

here is my .gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9'
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.inhatc.jh.yourplaylist'
        minSdkVersion 20
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile files('libs/jaudiotagger-2.2.4-SNAPSHOT.jar')
    compile files('libs/glide-3.4.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-api-services-youtube-v3-rev183-1.22.0.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.0.1'
    // Google Api Client library and Android extension
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.22.0'
    // Change to the API you want to access:
    // Below is just an example for People REST API access
    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-people:v1-rev4-1.22.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: please provide the gradle stacktrace (run it with `--debug` or `--info`)

Comment: Try to clean your project, sometimes it happens with me and a clean build solves it

Comment: i tried clean and rebuild project yesterday :l

Answer (score 0):

today solved my problem
i miss lib/.jar files and .gradle dependencies